# Homework - Ideal gas law

Tags: gas-laws

I don't understand how to find the volume in this problem..

A flask containing 63.2 mL of neon gas was collected over water at 21C and 788 mm Hg. What is this volume of gas at STP? (WVP at 21C = 18.6 mm Hg)

Comment: Hint: what do you know about the partial pressures of the gases?  What is contributing to the 788 mmHg?

Comment: If you edit the question to reflect your initial efforts, you can flag it to be reopened.  As of now, you have just copied your homework problem in as a question.  More ideal would be if you could pinpoint the areas that are troubling you and ask a more conceptual question.

Comment: This question serves as a *bad example* for the [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141).